# What is the name of 80's or 90's paperback with a woman in a red jumpsuit holding a bag of crystal shards on the cover?

Tags: story-identification, cover-art

My dad had this book in his library and the cover was very memorable.  The book was lost at some point and neither of us can remember the title or author.  If I remember correctly, I believe the woman on the cover was riding some kind of motorcycle or hover bike (a bit reminiscent of the anime 'Akira').  I think the character was a crystal hunter.  Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you're thinking of Anne McCaffrey's "[Killashandra](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/238961.Killashandra)"; The second book in the [Crystal Singer](https://www.goodreads.com/series/43910-crystal-singer) series.

[image: Killashandra]

The main character is called a "Crystal singer" and makes money by finding and selling rare crystals.

Comment: thats it!! Thanks a bunch.  My mind has been put to ease, at least in this respect!

Answer (score 4):

Further to MEGR's answer, the omnibus edition of the [Crystal Singer series](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/61969.Crystal_Singer_Omnibus) also featured the lady with the crystals as well as a better picture of the hovering bike;

[image]